# BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP caused C++ Builder 10.1 to crash to desktop

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I am writing a VCL componenet, TGIcon, to mimic the Icons in windows desktop, it has been working fine until I decided to add MouseEnter and MouseLeave events to the component. I followed guides from: [Embarcadero Community](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/162-programming/15317-writing-a-vcl-component-in-c-which-defines-its-own-events)

and here is my code (header):

```
class PACKAGE TGIcon : public TGraphicControl
{
    private:
        AnsiString FCaption;
        TPngImage *FIcon, *FDIcon;
        TFont *FFont;
        TNotifyEvent FOnMouseEnter;
        TNotifyEvent FOnMouseLeave;

        void __fastcall CMMouseEnter(TMessage &Message);
        void __fastcall CMMouseLeave(TMessage &Message);

        BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
            MESSAGE_HANDLER(CM_MOUSEENTER, TMessage, CMMouseEnter)
            MESSAGE_HANDLER(CM_MOUSELEAVE, TMessage, CMMouseLeave)
        END_MESSAGE_MAP(TGIcon)

    protected:
        virtual void __fastcall Paint();
        void __fastcall SetCaption(AnsiString value);
        void __fastcall SetIcon(TPngImage *value);
        void __fastcall SetFont(TFont *value);

    public:
        __fastcall TGIcon(TComponent* Owner);
        __fastcall ~TGIcon();
        void __fastcall MakeGray(void);

    __published:
        __property AnsiString Caption = {read=FCaption, write=SetCaption, nodefault};
        __property TPngImage  *Icon   = {read=FIcon, write=SetIcon};
        __property TFont      *Font   = {read=FFont, write=SetFont};
        __property Parent;
        __property Enabled;
        __property OnClick;

        __property TNotifyEvent OnMouseEnter = {read=FOnMouseEnter, write=FOnMouseEnter};
        __property TNotifyEvent OnMouseLeave = {read=FOnMouseLeave, write=FOnMouseLeave};
};
```

Whenever I try to place the component on a Form, the IDE (C++ Builder Starter) would crash to desktop. I have traced the source of problem to be the "BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP...END_MESSAGE_MAP" part. If I comment out that part, the component works fine.

I used to have the same component working in C++Builder XE5 (Professional) but since that's owned by a company I no longer work with, I don't have the binary of the component, so I have to re-write it here. As far as I can remember, what I did is exactly the same as the one I wrote in XE5, that one works but this one would crash the IDE, **no error message, no Access Violation, just plain CTD.**

Can someone please help, is there anything I need to do to make this work in C++ Builder 10.1 (Berlin) Starter Edition? Is this a bug of C++Builder or is this what cannot be done in Starter Edition, that it only can be done in the 'paid' editions?? Or is this method already obsolete? If so please show me how the "modernized" C++ Builder do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link you provide is a really-really old article (almost 20 years old). What concerns me about that is using `__fastcall` calling convention. I haven't been working with these message handlers for a while, so the following statement might be incorrect, but maybe those functions should be using `__stdcall` convention instead (or, none at all). At least, you could give it a try. For some more context regarding these calling conventions, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047758/cdecl-stdcall-and-fastcall-are-all-called-the-exact-same-way).

Comment: Tried the __stdcall, still CTD. I know the article is old, I have been using that type of event handling since C++ Builder 6.0. I knew it is going obsolete when in XE5 complaint about the inline code of the BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP, but Embarcadero isn't updating any information on this at all, at least I couldn't find any via Google. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `MESSAGE_MAP` is terminated incorrectly.  In the `END_MESSAGE_MAP` macro, you must specify the **base class** that your component derives from (`TGraphicControl`).

A `MESSAGE_MAP` is just a fancy way to override the virtual `Dispatch()` method, where:

- `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` declares and opens the overridden method, and opens a `switch` statement
- `MESSAGE_HANDLER` (use `VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER` instead if your project uses ATL) declares `case` statements for the `switch`
- `END_MESSAGE_MAP` calls the `Dispatch()` method of the specified class for unhandled messages, closes the `switch`, and closes the overridden method.

Here are the declarations from `sysmac.h`:

```
#define BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP   virtual void __fastcall Dispatch(void *Message) \
        {                                           \
          switch  (((PMessage)Message)->Msg)        \
          {
```

```
#define VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(msg,type,meth)          \
          case    msg:                              \
            meth(*((type *)Message));               \
            break;

// NOTE: ATL defines a MESSAGE_HANDLER macro which conflicts with VCL's macro. The
//       VCL macro has been renamed to VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER. If you are not using ATL,
//       MESSAGE_HANDLER is defined as in previous versions of BCB.
//
#if !defined(USING_ATL) && !defined(USING_ATLVCL) && !defined(INC_ATL_HEADERS)
#define MESSAGE_HANDLER  VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER
#endif // ATL_COMPAT
```

```
#define END_MESSAGE_MAP(base)           default:    \
                        base::Dispatch(Message);    \
                        break;                      \
          }                                         \
        }
```

So, this code:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(CM_MOUSEENTER, TMessage, CMMouseEnter)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(CM_MOUSELEAVE, TMessage, CMMouseLeave)
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TGIcon) // <-- error!
```

Gets translated by the preprocessor to this code, which is what the compiler sees:

```
virtual void __fastcall Dispatch(void *Message)
{
    switch (((PMessage)Message)->Msg)
    {
        case CM_MOUSEENTER:
            CMMouseEnter(*((TMessage *)Message));
            break;

        case CM_MOUSELEAVE:
            CMMouseLeave(*((TMessage *)Message));
            break;

        default:
            TGIcon::Dispatch(Message); // <-- recursive loop!
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, since you are specifying your own component class (`TGIcon`) instead of the base class (`TGraphicControl`) in `END_MESSAGE_MAP`, you are creating an endless recursion loop when the component receives an unhandled message.  `TGIcon::Dispatch()` is calling `TGIcon::Dispatch()` again.  It needs to call `TGraphicControl::Dispatch()` instead (so do your `CMMouseEnter()` and `CMMouseLeave()` methods):

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(CM_MOUSEENTER, TMessage, CMMouseEnter)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(CM_MOUSELEAVE, TMessage, CMMouseLeave)
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TGraphicControl) // <-- fixed!
```

Comment: Yes indeed...how silly of me for forgetting about this... Case solved, thanks a lot, Remy Lebeau.